# useState makes dynamic styling apply late

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, react-hooks

I'm working on Nextjs app. Here's what I have inside my client side component:

```js
const [view, setView] = useState<string[]>(["all"]);

const story = stories?.holidays;
const joke = stories?.jokes;
const idiom = stories?.idioms;
const factoid = stories?.culturalTips;

const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    const target = e.currentTarget as HTMLButtonElement;
    const value = target.innerText.toLowerCase();

    setView((prevState) => {
      if (value === "all") {
        return ["all"];
      } else {
        // If any other filter is clicked while "all" is selected, deselect "all"
        if (prevState.includes("all")) {
          return [value];
        } else {
          // For other filters, toggle their selection status
          if (prevState.includes(value)) {
            const filteredView = prevState.filter(v => v !== value);
            //Checks if no filter is selected, if so selects "all"
            return filteredView.length === 0 ? ["all"] : filteredView;
          } else {
            return [...prevState, value];
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

return (
    <Flex>
      <Button
        justifyContent={'center'}
        backgroundColor={view.includes('all') ? 'gray.200' : 'orange.50'}
        textColor={view.includes('all') ? 'black' : 'white'}
        disabled={isLoading}
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
      >
        <Text fontSize={'sm'}>All</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button
        justifyContent={'center'}
        backgroundColor={view.includes('story') ? 'gray.200' : 'orange.50'}
        textColor={view.includes('story') ? 'black' : 'white'}
        disabled={isLoading}
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
      >
      // the rest of the buttons
    </Flex>
    {factoid &&
    story &&
    idiom &&
    joke &&
    (view.includes('all') || view.includes('story')) &&
    story.map((holidayValue, idx) => (
    <Box
      border={'1px solid #E2E2E2'}
      borderRadius={'10px'}
      padding={'20px'}
      my={'20px'}
      boxShadow="lg"
      key={idx}
    >
      <Image
        width={40}
        height={40}
        className="stories-icon"
        src={storyImg}
        alt="story"
      />
      <Text>{holidayValue}</Text>
    </Box>
    ))}
    // the same 3 more times for the joke, idiom, factoid
)
```

The goal is to be able apply multiple filters at the same time. If none filters are applied, "All" is selected. If any filter is unapplied, the button goes to the original state. Button styling is dynamic and depends on the view state. The issue is that it gets applied one step late than it should. I think it's because of asynchronous nature of `useState`, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm using Chakra UI but I don't think it's causing any issue. The example is on the GIF below:

[image: illustration of the issue]

Comment: What does *"it's applied one step late than it should"* mean? In other words, it is unclear what is the desired functionality here. Could you clarify?

Comment: @tao as you can see on the gif, when the filter is applied, it changes color from orange to gray. When I unapply it, I expect it to turn orange right when I click it, but it does it only when I interact with the next filter. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Note that onClick only kicks in _after_ the release. You probably at the very least want to hook into the touch start/mouse down events.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans good to know, thank you

Comment: Does [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-leftpad-q6v8cd?file=/src/App.js) work as intended? The idea is you should never include `'all'` in activeFilters (or whatever you called it in your example). `'all'` is a derived state. It's value is determined by `filters.length === activeFilters.length` (in my example).

Comment: Note that when you have the problem, you get white text with gray background, although it should white on orange or black on gray. This means that something overrides the background. Try removing `disabled={isLoading}` from the buttons, and check it.

Comment: @tao unfortunately, no. The idea is that "All" is the default value. When any other filter button is clicked, "All" gets deselected. At the same time, if all 4 buttons except "All" are clicked (selected), "All" is still not selected.

Comment: @OriDrori I removed `disabled={isLoading}` and still having the same issue

Comment: Understood, updated the example with the described logic.

Comment: @tao last thing, if "All" is selected, it deselects all other filters

Comment: Did you mean: *"When All is clicked I want all filters removed"*? If so, check the example again. Your English is not very clear, at least to me.

Comment: @tao sorry, I changed my comment. Yes, that is what I meant -> "When All is clicked I want all filters removed"

Comment: @tao thank you so much for your help! I've been trying to connect it to my component. Still working on it. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @tao can you publish your solution so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise on not adding `'all'` filter in the array of active filters at any time. The `'all'` filter (which means *"all items"*, a.k.a. *"no filters"*) is a state derived from `!activeFilters.length`.

Here's a component featuring the requested functionality ([codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wizardly-jackson-2zjynf)):

```
import * as React from 'react'

export const FilterButtons: React.FC<object> = () => {
  const [activeFilters, setActiveFilters] = React.useState<string[]>([])

  const filters = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
  const all = !activeFilters.length

  const toggleFilter = (filter?: string) =>
    setActiveFilters((prevState) =>
      filter
        ? prevState.includes(filter)
          ? prevState.filter((f) => f !== filter)
          : filters.length - prevState.length !== 1
          ? [...prevState, filter]
          : []
        : []
    )

  return (
    <>
      {filters.map((filter) => (
        <button
          key={filter}
          onClick={() => toggleFilter(filter)}
          className={activeFilters.includes(filter) ? 'active' : ''}
        >
          {filter}
        </button>
      ))}
      <button
        className={all ? 'active' : ''}
        onClick={() => toggleFilter()}
        disabled={all}
      >
        all
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Note the only state I'm using is `activeFilters`, because nothing else changes.

If the nested ternaries inside `toggleFilter` are difficult to read, here's a more explicit version:

```
function toggleFilter(filter?: string) {
  setActiveFilters((prevState) => {
    if (filter) {
      if (prevState.includes(filter)) {
        // remove filter
        return prevState.filter((f) => f !== filter)
      } else if (filters.length - prevState.length !== 1) {
        // add filter
        return [...prevState, filter]
      }
    }
    // remove all filters
    return []
  })
}
```